# Searching strings in a single column in a datatable jquery

Tags: jquery, search, datatable, datatables

I'm using jquery datatable, and I want to search the rows where I can find some words in a single column. 
For example, I want to find the rows which contain an array of words.

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation? https://datatables.net/reference/api/search() What have you tried.

Comment: I tried to use it but i dont know how to loop throught this datatable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is to put an input element in the column you want to search. Then you need to add a listener to this input that will call a couple DataTables methods. My implementation looks something like this:

```
$("#searchInput").on('keyup change', function (e) {
    if(e.which == 13) {
        table
            .column($(this).parent().index() + ':visible')
            .search(this.value)
            .draw();
    }
});
```

The e.which == 13 makes the search only occur when enter is pressed. This was my preference, you can do it on any keyup if you prefer.

$(this).parent().index() finds the column number of the  that the input is in.